# Creating a while loop for a Game

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I had a quick question about a code I have been working on today. I am creating a game that uses a while loop where the two opponents will have turns to "hit" one another until one of the players have 0 health points.

This is the code I have so far, although it is not working. Can anyone help?

```
done=False
while not done:
    if You.Hit_points>Opponent.Hit_points:
        move=raw_input("Would you like to make a move? (y/n) ")
        if move=="y":
            print "",You.name,"hit ",Opponent.name," by",You.Hit_points," hit points!"
            Opponent.Health=You.Hit_points+You.Skill_points+Opponent.Health
            print "Due to the hit",Opponent.name,"is left with",Opponent.Health," health points."
            print ("The Mighty Beast will make a move.")
            print "",Opponent.name,"hits",You.name,"by",Opponent.Hit_points,"points"
            You.Health=(Opponent.Hit_points-Opponent.Skill_points)+You.Health
            print "Due to the hit",You.name,"loses",Opponent.Hit_points,"points.Leaving",You.name,"with",You.Health,"health points."
            print "Now it is",Opponent.name,"'s turn to make a move"
            You.Health=You.Health-(Opponent.Hit_points+Opponent.Skill_points)
            print "Due to the hit",You.name,"is left with",You.Health,"health points."
    else:
        You.Hit_points==0
        move=="n"
        done=True
```

Comment: how is it not working? if it's not running it could be because `Opponent.Hit_points` is greater that `You.Hit_points` to start with

Comment: what is the error message your getting?

Comment: I am getting 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

```
if You.Hit_points>Opponent.Hit_points:
```

should probably be

```
if You.Hit_points > 0 and Opponent.Hit_points > 0
```

right? Otherwise as soon as `You`'s HP drops below `Opponent`'s--which could be after the first turn--the fight will end.